# Como promover nosso site?

Tags: debate, big-7

Esta é mais uma das [7 perguntas que toda nova comunidade deve fazer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) antes de se graduar.

> Isso está se tornando rapidamente um assunto quente em toda a rede: como promover o seu site e como chegar aos especialistas e colegas em sua indústria. Podemos falar de orçamentos e promoções, mas os meios e ideias sobre como chegar ao seu público-alvo tem que vir de você e sua comunidade. Tem que. Tem que, tem que, tem que! Nós simplesmente não somos especialistas em seu campo. Não temos as ligações, nem a experiência que você traz para a mesa. Você é tanto o nosso evangelista e nosso embaixador - e compartilhamento de links para excelentes perguntas e respostas é a melhor maneira de começar.
>
> Stack Overflow tem sido uma enorme história de sucesso na arena de programação em inglês. Mas esse sucesso precoce veio em grande parte à participação de Jeff Atwood e Joel Spolsky, ambos os blogueiros e celebridades cult em seu campo. Queremos que o mesmo sucesso para você e sua comunidade. É por isso que precisamos identificar o Jeffs e os Joels de sua indústria. Precisamos de blogueiros, especialistas podcasters, editores, celebridades... qualquer um que possa reunir as tropas, por assim dizer.

Para mais detalhes em: [uma receita para promover seu site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

---

Basicamente o texto foi tirado do que do blog oficial e do que se costuma fazer durante o beta de outros sites da rede. Não sei se o processo será exatamente, mas certamente podemos contribuir com informações úteis. Não precisamos ter ideias hoje, mas precisamos ajudar a SE com um guia do que fazer para divulgar o site quando ele for graduado.

Comment: Procure dar ideia mais específicas, dizer quem, onde, o que fazer. Ideias gerais e genéricas são boas também, mas a maioria delas a equipe SE já teve e sabe o que fazer. Precisamos de informações que eles não sabem como chegar nos especialistas desenvolvedores que falam português.

Comment: Uma dica: Procure no meta dos outros sites da rede por perguntas semelhantes de como eles promoveram seus sites. Muitas não ajudam o nosso caso, mas vai surgir algumas ideias originais desse "roubo" de ideias deles :)

Answer (score 15):

Distribuindo brindes para os participantes mais ativos =D

Como por exemplo camisetas legais e criativas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Stack Overflow T-shirt, 3rd anniversary edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108395/229289)

Imagina o pessoal indo para o trabalho, eventos, andando na rua com a camisa do SOPT fazendo propraganda?

Acredito que seja a forma mais barata de patrocínio além de atingir o público constantemente, e não apenas em um dia ou outro específico como por um exemplo um banner em um evento.

## Vocês não acham que é hora de algumas camisetas do <strike>Stack Exchange</strike> *StackOverflow em Português*?

Original: [Don't you think that it's time for some Stack Exchange shirts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77556/229289)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: pra qual email posso passar meu endereço? Meu tamanho é M. =P

Comment: Ou ainda a distribuição de adesivos do SOPT em eventos/conferências. Vai que ideia cola :D

Comment: @perdeu poisé, eu falei "brindes" no começo mas acabei só citando a camiseta no corpo da resposta, pois vi que já foi praticado em algumas situações. Mas adesivos, canecas, canetas, tudo seria bem-vindo tb :)

Comment: @perdeu ah, "em eventos/conferencias" eu não citei, seria algo fora do escopo da minha resposta, se você achar interessante pode criar sua resposta dando essa sugestão

Comment: Isso é *self-interest*, não *promotion* :)

Answer (score 6):

Poderíamos fazer uma Mala direta de divulgação aos emails de universidades e escolas técnicas para que elas repassem o email aos seus alunos, o que conteria neste email uma banner contendo uma descrição do SOpt (como ele funciona, as estatisticas) links para as áreas do site (incluindo o tour).

Comment: Algumas Universidades Federais divulgam o email acadêmico do seu quadro de professores.

Comment: Lista de docentes (junto com os emails academicos) do Instituto de Informatica da UFG (essa lista é pública) http://inf.ufg.br/docentes

Comment: `+1` - podiamos escolher algumas das perguntas do site que ainda não têm resposta para dar ao professor como desafio. Para ele ou para os alunos responderem.

Comment: Excelente @Sergio

Comment: Poderíamos colocar as perguntas com maior relevância (tanto teóricas como práticas)

Comment: Muito bom @Sergio

Comment: Muito bem pensado, posso tentar falar com alguns professores meus da Universidade do Minho, Braga...

Comment: Pois sim, acho que a lista de docentes é muito melhor que a de alunos. São os professores que queremos trazer pro nosso lado primeiro.

Answer (score 4):

Disponibilizando banners para os usuários que possuem blog ou página iguais aos [banners do SOPT usados no StackOverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1075/3117) e oferecendo medalhas em troca da quantidade de cliques por IP exclusivo que tiver no banner, assim como já ocorre por compartilhamento de links para perguntas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao invés de "Compartilhou **link**" seria "Compartilhou **banner**", a quantidade de IPs exclusivos não precisa ser a mesma.

Answer (score 3):

O Guilherme [me indicou](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/como-divulgar-o-nosso-site/147#comment383_147) esta discussão. Vou reproduzir parte da minha resposta lá:

> Como ferramenta social, eu recomendaria fuçar o site Social Bakers.
> Abaixo um link mostrando as melhores audiencias sobre Educação no YouTube Brasil (o site também tem dados sobre Facebook, Twitter e G+).
> É só ir lá, achar gente legal e espalhar a notícia :)
>
> http://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/youtube/channels/brazil/society/education/

<sub>Por favor, edite e acrescente nesta resposta sites legais que vc achou.

Assim saberemos quem andou fazendo propaganda onde.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a própria indexação do Google já cuida disso muito bem. Eu, por exemplo, descobri o site porque estava pesquisando alguma dúvida referente à programação ou configuração de servidores.

Claro que a divulgação no nicho especializado é interessante, mas acho que a melhor maneira de divulgar é produzindo bom conteúdo (cuja arquitetura do site força a comunidade a isso) e esperando o Google indexar isso corretamente.

Comment: Bom saber que já está dando para achar respostas aqui pelo Google mas isso não ajuda sabermos técnicas de divulgação extras que podemos fazer, que é o motivo da pergunta.

Comment: Meeh, acho que o assunto não é indexação automática, mas ações pro-ativas da comunidade. -1 . . . . . Que eu saiba, a indexação no Stack é top de linha.