# Como começar aqui no Stack Overflow em Português

Tags: suporte, destaque

Este site é muito diferente do que eu estou acostumado. Como eu aprendo rapidamente a usá-lo adequadamente?

Comment: Qual o equivalente em português para "lurk"? Com uma semana de lurking já dá pra ver como funciona o troço e começar vários níveis mais acima do que aterrizar de paraquedas atirando sem direção.... Acho que no SOen dá pra passar 1 ano inteiro só lurkando, encontrando soluções e sem postar nem uma misera pergunta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Básico

- Leia a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) e o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade)
- Ao contrário de fóruns e listas de discussão, este site se concentra em **perguntas** e **respostas**. Pense diferente, esqueça as discussões e conversas que encontra em fóruns e listas. Nossa organização privilegia perguntas e respostas limpas. O [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) que você já leu deixa claro como funciona.
- *Depois de obter alguma reputação certifique-se de [votar nas boas perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente), e negativamente nas perguntas e respostas ruins*!
- O objetivo é ter perguntas e respostas indexadas pelos buscadores, portanto não se preocupe se os posts são longos. Desde que tenham conteúdo relevante e não discussões, isso é ótimo.
- O que é o Stack Exchange e Stack Overflow em Português? Em resumo, é um site diferente que permite a troca de conhecimento de uma forma mais organizada que fóruns e listas. Elimina o ruído e por isso atrai especialistas que não tem tempo para conversas sem sentido que pouco ou nada ajudam. (Aguarde por bom material em português contando a história e os objetivos deste e outros sites da rede)

### Fazendo perguntas boas

- As pessoas vão votar na sua pergunta com base na sua qualidade, por isso [faça algum esforço](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)<sup>(em inglês por enquanto)</sup> para escrevê-la bem e obter atenção.
- Use tags para classificar a sua pergunta. Isso faz com que as perguntas fiquem mais fáceis de identificar na primeira página e nas comunidades específicas.
- Não poste a mesma pergunta mais de uma vez. Se a sua pergunta não for respondida, a comunidade de usuários dará o devido destaque a ela conforme sua qualidade.
- Sinta-se à vontade para continuar melhorando sua pergunta. Edite, edite e edite. As pessoas tendem a ajudar/votar em pessoas que estão ativamente tentando entender o problema.
- Se você não está conseguindo respostas, provavelmente sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Use a formatação para organizar a pergunta. Poste seu código ou outras informações além de texto que ajudem entender seu problema. Não use comentários para acrescentar novas informações, edite a pergunta.
- Seja objetivo, vá direto ao ponto do problema sem deixar de colocar informações suficientes. Lembre-se que as pessoas não conhecem sue problema e a situação que você se encontra. Evite saudações, agradecimentos ou expressões desnecessárias como "meu problema é o seguinte" ou "alguém pode me ajudar". Não acrescenta nada à pergunta. Sabemos que você é educado. Pense que você está criando uma pergunta para uma prova/teste. Não cabe conversa na pergunta.
- Se você acabar encontrando uma resposta sozinho, responda sua própria pergunta para que as futuros usuários possam se beneficiar dela!
- Se alguém responde a sua pergunta, aceite-a como a resposta mais correta. Este é um passo importante e premia as pessoas que tentam ajudá-lo.
- Uma pergunta por vez. É mais fácil procurar por duplicatas e votar na qualidade de respostas quando você faz uma pergunta por post em vez de um grande post com várias perguntas.

### Dando boas respostas

- Não post só links para recursos aleatórios na internet. Qualquer pessoa pode pesquisar no Google. Se a informação é **boa e sob uma licença aberta**, basta colocar seu texto na resposta (não se esqueça de linkar e creditar o autor). Links podem ficar desatualizados ou morrer. Precisamos de respostas duradouras.
- Editar, editar, editar deve ser seu mantra. Se você tem uma boa resposta e alguém acrescenta mais detalhes, aproveite a oportunidade, e lembre-se sempre de respeitar o trabalho de um indivíduo.
- A resposta deve só responder a pergunta e fornecer qualquer informação útil para o autor e para outras pessoas .Nuca suponha que está só respondendo ao autor. Respostas devem ser fornecidas para todos usufruírem. E nós sabemos que você tem a esperança de ter ajudado.
- Os comentários são como um "meta" para a resposta. *Não fique fazendo pingue-pongue em comentários com novas informações. Quando alguém deixa um comentário com mais informações ou algo assim, basta adicionar as informações à sua pergunta diretamente. *Se as pessoas postam atualizações em um comentário peça-lhe para adicionar à sua pergunta, que é onde o Stack Exchange brilha: atualizações devem acontecer nas respostas e as perguntas, de modo que quando você terminar todo processo, as pessoas não terão que acompanhar a conversa para entender tudo. Apenas a resposta final com a solução deve ser destacada.
- Você pode excluir coisas! Exclua tudo que é temporário, que foi importante para chegar ao resultado final ma que não vai ajudar ninguém no futuro. Deixe as perguntas e respostas reinarem na sua forma final. Elimine o que não é mais necessário para entender o problema.

  Se não consegue editar com algo melhor, apague o que não funcionou, o que está atraindo votos negativos. Deixe o site limpo.
- Respostas não devem ser usadas para comentários, para perguntar ao autor. Se você ainda não tem reputação suficiente para comentar, aguarde, não tente burlar o sistema. Isso é mal visto e atrai reações negativas. A limitação existe por uma boa razão.

### Espalhe para todos

- Precisamos de ajuda para obter mais usuários, [dê algumas ideias](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/633/como-promover-nosso-site) sobre como divulgar o site.

Comment: Este post pode linkado para orientar os iniciantes sobre comportamento adequado. Ajude melhorar esta mini FAQ para iniciantes. Deve conter o que for mais relevante e o que os iniciantes mais tem dificuldade. Não deve responder tudo o que um iniciante precisa saber, só o básico para ele iniciar corretamente. Torne o post mais objetivo **E** coloque mais informações relevantes.