# O banner "C# é irritante. Inglês também" não é ofensivo?

Tags: debate

Algumas vezes, quando acesso o stackoverflow.com, aparece esse banner anunciando o Stackoverflow em português com os seguintes dizeres: "C# é irritante. Inglês também.".

Eu sou programador Java, mas acho que esse tipo de banner é ofensivo para os programadores C#.

O stackoverflow sempre foi uma comunidade agnóstica no que diz respeito a linguagens. Um dos usuários mais famosos do Stackoverflow, Jon Skeet, é desenvolvedor C#.

Programadores C# podem sentir que não sem bem-vindos aqui.

Vocês acham que esse banner deve ser permanecer ou ser removido?

Comment: Embora eu não veja problema com o banner, não é difícil encontrar quem se ofenda. Isso tem que ser levado em consideração.

Comment: De verdade? Também sou Javeiro mas tenhomuito apreço pelo C#. Se eu visse um Banner: "Java is annoying. So is portuguese!" anunciando a nova Stack Overflow em inglês eu daria muita risada e clicaria no *banner*. Acho que temos que conversar o senso de humor em uma comunidade *nerd*.

Comment: Eu acho a versão em inglês do @AnthonyAccioly muito mais engraçada que em português. Na tradução perde um pouco a graça. Sou a favor do senso de humor e não acho o anúncio ofensivo, somente meio sem-graça...

Comment: Hoje um cara muito irritado com o banner criou uma publicação com a tag Java e falou um monte de besteira. Não imaginei que pudesse chegar a esse ponto, mas realmente, "C# é ofensivo" pode deixar algumas pessoas extremamente irritadas.

Comment: Só não entendi porque não colocaram php no lugar de C# :)

Answer (score 18):

*Eu respondi um email sobre isso agora pouco, então lá vai grande parte do que eu disse:*

A plataforma Stack Exchange é totalmente desenvolvida em C#, e a comunidade .NET é muito grande e importante dentro do site. Da mesma forma, a imensa maioria das pessoas que trabalham aqui (e dos nossos usuários) têm o inglês como língua nativa. Todos nós que trabalhamos nos anúncios - que, tirando eu, são todos americanos - nos esforçamos para criar coisas que fossem ser imediatamente reconhecidas por programadores, e que fossem bem diretas quanto à mensagem que queríamos passar. Algumas coisas funcionavam bem em inglês, mas não em português. Outras eram muito boas em português, mas pareciam esquisitas em inglês. O anúncio de "Inglês é irritante" é um dos que funcionavam bem em ambas as línguas sendo, inclusive, sugerido por um dos americanos.

Muitos dos nossos programadores (no Brasil, em Portugal ou outro país lusófono) sentem muita dificuldade em participar de comunidades em inglês. A língua é uma barreira difícil de se transpor, já que atingir um nível "natural" com uma língua estrangeira requer anos de estudo e prática.

Quando criamos o anúncio, não queríamos denegrir a linguagem, seja C# ou inglês. Não há motivo para isso. Queríamos sim tocar num ponto comum à muitas pessoas que visitam o SO sem um conhecimento amplo de inglês. É difícil, irritante e desanimador fazer parte de uma comunidade que não fala a sua língua. Além disso, o jeito mais direto de parar no Stack Overflow é quando se está passando raiva com algum problema, e nessas horas é fácil botar a culpa na línguagem, na plataforma, na IDE, no computador, no universo.

Talvez devêssemos ter criado versões com outras linguagens de programação, de forma a não parecer tendencioso contra uma ou outra comunidade. Mas nada no SOPT é feito com o intuito de atacar uma comunidade. Queremos que todos os programadores visitem e gostem do site e que ele seja um ambiente sadio de interação entre todos.

## Adendo

Vendo a conversa e as sugestões do @bfavaretto e do @AnthonyAccioly nos comentários eu lembrei de algo relevante que li um tempo atrás. O resumo, [nesse link](http://mappingignorance.org/2014/02/03/mandela-was-right-the-foreign-language-effect/) - em inglês - gira em torno de uma frase de Nelson Mandela:

> If you talk to a man in a language he understands, that goes to his head. If you talk to him in his language, that goes to his heart.
>
> ---
>
> *Ao falar com o outro numa língua que ele entende, a mensagem vai para a cabeça. Se você falar a língua dele, vai para o coração.*

O post fala sobre pesquisas que corroboram essa idéia. De que nós assimilamos de formas diferentes a **mesma mensagem**, quando ela se encontra numa língua não nativa. Mesmo quando somos fluentes.

Existe sim uma diferença cultural entre Brasileiros, Portugueses, Americanos, Tchecos, etc, etc e etc. Obviamente certas mensagens não podem ser traduzidas da mesma forma, e existem diferenças culturais a se considerar. Tudo isso ser verdade **não** implica que uma mensagem que alguém poliglota entende de formas diferentes seja realmente diferente.

O que eu quero dizer é que:

> C# is annoying. So is English

Que era a versão original do banner, seja menos passível de causar estranhamento só porque Inglês e Português são línguas diferentes. Se houvesse um banner como esse no SO, nós receberíamos o mesmo tipo de reclamação. Para nativos de outras línguas ela provavelmente não causaria reação alguma dessa forma, apenas por estar em outra língua.

A versão original desse banner dizia:

> C# é difícil. Inglês também.

Alguns de vocês vão achar que é uma versão melhor. Mas outros vão pensar que ela chama os usuários lusófonos do SO de burros, ou incapazes de falar inglês. E nós sempre precisamos ficar atentos à todas as possíveis interpretações que uma mensagem pública pode ter.

Criar um banner como esse - ou os outros - é sempre um tiro no escuro. Uma mensagem contundente, sem o "pode ser", normalmente é muito mais efetiva mas tem chances maiores de gerar reações adversas. Quando se soma à isso variáveis multi-culturais e multi-linguísticas os riscos são ainda maiores. Por isso nós sempre temos muito cuidado quando criamos as coisas para o site.

## Bônus!

Essa é uma foto dos primeiros mockups que nós fizemos. Algumas coisas aí mudaram, outras não foram pro ar, e algumas que foram para o ar não estavam aí. Nela ainda era a versão original do banner de C#:

[image: Créditos pro Sam Brand, pelos desenhos e várias das ideias]

Comment: Gabe, estava pensando sobre esse assunto hoje (sim, eu penso em coisas esquisitas durante o dia), e cheguei a conclusão que existe uma diferença cultural que leva a versão em português a soar ofensiva em relação à sua tradução em inglês. Popularmente sempre achei a comunicação em inglês extremamente direta *"is"*. Não quero de nenhuma forma criar um esteriótipo, mas penso que o humor para países latinos (especialmente lusófilos) tem que ser mais gingado *"can be"*. Enfim, meu ponto é que uma construção circunstancial do tipo "*C# pode ser irritante, inglês também."* talvez seja melhor aceita.

Comment: @bfavaretto, como você comentou sobre o assunto, gostaria da sua opinião. Só numa comunidade de TI um banner gera uma discussão sobre linguista e diferenças culturais entre latinos e anglo-saxões (espero não estar ofendendo ninguém, mas isso é algo que reparei convivendo com estrangeiros - apenas uma teoria minha).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Faz sentido o que você disse, o "pode ser" ameniza a afirmação, bem no estilo latino-americano. Acho que essa mudança resolveria. E é verdade, profissionais de TI, especialmente programadores, adoram discutir esse tipo de coisa; programadores podem ser irritantes! :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Off-topic: vi seu comentário por sorte; ele não gerou notificação (geraria caso eu tivesse comentado antes nesta resposta, ou editado a resposta).

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque bfavaretto, eu sempre esqueço que o @ não é um sistema global de notificação.

Comment: Eu gostei bastante da sugestão "C# pode ser irritante, inglês também."

Comment: "Mundó"? De onde saiu isso? :D Gostei bastante de "Pergunte / Responda / Programe", bem objetivo. Não vingou?

Comment: @bfavaretto É. Não lembro porque... Mas ele não foi nem pra primeira rodada de layouts

Comment: Eu sou "Javeiro" e não fico nada irritado quando falam que Java é irritante por N motivos. Pelo contrário, um bom profissional tem que reconhecer os pontos fracos das tecnologias tanto quanto os fortes. Ficar defendendo o próprio ego só bitola as pessoas.

Comment: @utluiz, o que você disse chama-se maturidade, eu sou desenvolvedor C# e PHP e não fico irritado com esse Banner mais de certa forma abre precedentes para qualquer um dizer o que pensa, o ser humano é assim. Só lembrando que agora C# VNext é mais open source do que nunca.