# Ajude a escolher nossos novos banners!

Tags: debate, concurso

> ### Escolhemos nossos banners!
>
> #### Veja a lista dos escolhidos [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5049)!

Quando o SOpt foi lançado, nós criamos um conjunto de banners para aparecerem no Stack Overflow original para pessoas de países lusófonos, ou que tivessem seus navegadores configurados para português. Era uma maneira de avisar nossos intrépidos usuários de que agora eles tinham a oportunidade de participar de um site em sua própria língua.

Bom, nem todos os banners [foram um sucesso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1070). E hoje, mais de 2 anos depois, os que estão no ar estão, como eu carinhosamente descrevi numa reunião:

> Com o nome errado, com a logo errada, com a cor errada e do tamanho errado.
>
> <sup>(Gabe, 2016)</sup>

Confiram vocês mesmos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde a criação desses banners, nós já [mudamos a logomarca da empresa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4354/), o Stack Overflow em Português ganhou um tom de verde oficial e uma logo própria, o tamanho da barra de propagandas [mudou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272563/) e, até não muito tempo atrás, [eles ainda diziam "beta"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317328/). Enfim, nada bom... nada bom...

### Chegou a hora de mudar

E gostaríamos da ajuda de vocês sobre o que colocar nesses novos banners!

Eles vão ser o convite pra quem quiser vir participar do SOpt (sim, *mais novatos!*). O cartão de visitas da nossa comunidade. Então nada mais justo que digam o que vocês quiserem que digam. Só alguns pontos, pra manter as coisas em ordem:

1. **Obviamente**, mantenham a decência.
2. O desenho dos banners vai ficar à cargo da nossa equipe de design, mas nada impede que alguém que se sinta confortável com Photoshop ou similares e deixe a imaginação fluir.
3. Queremos 5 banners diferentes.
4. O prazo é sexta feira, dia 29 de abril.

E, só pra deixar mais interessante, **as 5 sugestões mais votadas ganham uma camiseta!**

Botem seus neurônios mais "marketeiros" pra funcionar e vamos ver o que acontece.

## Atualização

Como eu disse: **não é necessário desenhar o banner**. Apenas a frase já tá ótimo.

Mas, como tem gente cheia de disposição e talento, aqui vão todos as nossas logos e cores em diversos formatos e sabores:
[image: GIF]
[image: JPG]
[image: PNG]
[image: Verde]

## Atualização 2 - O Retorno

O concurso é pra descobrir qual são banners favoritos de vocês, não pra descobrir quais são os melhores de acordo com o comitê de análise do Meta. Além disso, não queremos dar margem pra ninguém sair votando contra sugestões só pra tentar ganhar posições.

### Então na contagem final *só vão valer os upvotes*

O que é bom que também deixa a lista de ganhadores menos óbvia `:D`

Comment: A camiseta é com o logo certo? /s

Comment: @Bacco Não posso afirmar, mas acho que não. kkk

Comment: @Bacco ganhe o concurso é descubra!

Comment: @Gabe é só para desenhar os banners ou vale sugestões de frases também? No caso as frases que serão usadas no banners.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho sugestão de frases é o que queremos!

Comment: Prenda de aniversário? :P

Comment: Estouro de pilha não seria legal. Seria como traduzir a rede de lanches Subway para Metrô, ou nem isso, Caminho Subterrâneo

Comment: Poderia fornecer o logo em um bom tamanho pra podermos trabalharmos algumas ideias?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tá lá!

Comment: @LFZiron "Estouro de pilha" é o nome da sala de chat

Comment: @Gabe se sobrar alguma camisa por favor não se esqueça do pessoal do [devday](http://devday.devisland.com/)kkkkkkkk

Comment: @Gabe não era melhor o pessoal separar os banners? Está toda a gente com vários, quais é que ganham? Todos de cada pessoa?

Comment: @JorgeB. Separar o banner poderia fazer alguém "ganhar" várias vezes, ou uma ideia boa ser ignorada porque o autor "já ganhou". Quando o concurso acabar, vou fazer um outro post contendo só as sugestões que ganharem aqui, e o número final de banners que queremos, e a comundiade pode escolher quais exatamente vão pro ar.

Comment: @Gabe ok, percebi.

Answer (score 21):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

<sub>Imagem meramente ilustrativa para dar ênfase no exemplo :P</sub>

Comment: E esse portugol misturado com Javascript jovem?

Comment: Pensei em fazer em C#, mas ia ficar meio estranho :P

Comment: Coisas feias tem que ser em javascript ou php... ce la vi

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isso foi ofensivo kkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 18):

Já que o @Gabe disse que quer somente a frase, nem me preocupei em fazer uma imagem "descente". Mas o sentido da frase é esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Na logo era para ser a que fala Stackoverflow em português, e não estouro de pilha, mas estava com preguiça de achar a certa! kkkkkkk
> Vale lembrar que foi feita no paint, já que o que busca não é uma logo definitiva, e sim ideias.

Ou então,

> Cansado de traduzir? Pergunte em português!

Answer (score 13):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

;)

Comment: ótimo kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Muita gente não vai gistar da maioria, mas é muito bom :D

Answer (score 12):

Lembrei-me destas três, mas todos os trocadilhos com SO tem direitos de autor :P

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> SO em Português podes perguntar!

---

> SO queres tirar uma dúvida? Tira em Português!

Comment: "SO pra quem fala Português!" é uma ideia genial (ótimo trocadilho)! :)

Comment: Acho que se vc fizer um banner simples com essa frase dá mais visibilidade pro seu post (e facilita a você ganhar mais votos), heim Jorge? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira está bom assim? ;)

Comment: Muito bom! Mas eu ainda colocaria um risco de cor diferente (e no estilo "feito a mão") acima da letra "o" do "SO", pra fazer as vezes do acento agudo. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira estou a tentar perceber a tua ideia mas não estou a chegar lá...

Comment: Eu também não sou bom em desenhos, mas o que eu quis dizer é algo assim: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GWJ3z.png

Comment: @LuizVieira que achas assim?

Comment: HAHAHA Muito bom! Gostei ainda mais!

Comment: @LuizVieira já sei a quem recorrer para ter emprego na área de design :D

Answer (score 11):

StackOverflow em português: Todas as linguagens na sua língua

Answer (score 10):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(**Não precisa ser assim o banner**) mas acho que a frase ficou legal ^.^

Answer (score 9):

```
Uma pilha de soluções para uma pilha de problemas
```

---

```
if( $language === 'pt' )
{
    echo "Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :)"
}
```

Comment: Gostei da ideia, só não gostei da linguagem "demo". kkkk
+1 mesmo assim.

Comment: @Randrade, foi 'demo', mas a ideia seria usar outras juntas. Meu exemplo em outras linguagens seria um loop infinito... rs

Comment: @PapaCharlie `if( $linguagem ` ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. no caso seria `if( $idioma )` :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie era para ficar quase igual, mas pode ser linguagem, lingua, idioma. É como quiseres.

Answer (score 8):

Não sei por que, deve ser os meus 15 anos assistindo chaves que me trazem essa referencia, mas quando alguém esta pedindo ajuda esta frase me vem a cabeça:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O foco aqui é apenas o texto, não quis pegar imagens autorais para mixar nela :)

Me lembrou também outra frase dele:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou até aquele outro antigo seriado  aquela frase que não sai da cabeça, todo mundo odeia o Chris:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São frases que fazem uma grande referencia, se utilizadas para o bem podem ser incríveis.

Answer (score 7):

Gosto do banner "Não encontrou o que procurava? Que tal perguntar em português?".

Nessa linha eu sugiro mais frases para serem apresentadas no SO original usando o mesmo banner:

> Já pensou se todas as respostas estivessem em português?

ou

> Já quis fazer uma pergunta, mas não sabe escrever bem em inglês?

Answer (score 6):

```
try
{
    question("stackoverflow.com");
}
catch(UnclearWhatYouAreAsking e)
{
    pergunta("pt.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Se inglês para ti é chinês, pergunta no Stackoverflow em português.

Answer (score 5):

1)

> Deixe sua pilha de dúvidas com os especialistas do StackOverflow em português.

2)

> Array Index Out of Bounds?
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?
>
> dúvidas e problema com programação?
>
> Agora existe um stack overflow na medida exata e na sua lingua, bem vindo stack overflow em português \o/.

Answer (score 4):

Separei algumas frases para sugestão:

> Estouro de Pilha.
>   De programador para programador.

---

> Para toda pergunta nós temos uma resposta.
>   Stackoverflow em Português.

---

> Stackoverflow em Português.
>   Feito em Português para você que fala Português.

Comment: gosto da primeira +1

Answer (score 4):

Eu ainda não tive tempo de desenhar, mas as ideias seriam esta:

> Stack Overflow agora mais próximo de você
>
> Pergunte em português

E

> Pergunte em português para o seu conforto

Answer (score 3):

```
Em chuva de perguntas, as respostas são em Português, Stackoverflow em Português.
```

---

```
Em terra de duvidas, quem responde em Português é REI, Stackoverflow em Português.
```

Answer (score 2):

SOpt -  Onde o problema acha a solução.