# Ajude a escolher nossos novos banners! Parte 2!

Tags: debate, concurso

Pra mim é muito claro que muitos de vocês estão na carreira errada e deviam urgentemente trabalhar com publicidade. E que o nosso próximo site tem que ser o *Ad Overflow em Português*.

Meus parabéns! As sugestões de vocês foram sensacionais e os novos banners vão ficar espetaculares. Muito melhores que os nossos originais.

Agora chegou a hora da verdade! Como eu disse [no outro post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4999):

> O concurso é pra descobrir qual são banners favoritos de vocês, não pra descobrir quais são os melhores de acordo com o comitê de análise do Meta. Além disso, não queremos dar margem pra ninguém sair votando contra sugestões só pra tentar ganhar posições.

Então, quais foram as sugestões mais votadas? Quem ganhou?

```
Nome       Upvotes Downvotes Pontuação
---------  ------- --------- ---------
jbueno     21      0         21
Randrade   19      1         18
OnoSendai  15      2         13
Jorge B.   12      0         12
Fabiano    11      0         11
```

<sup>*[query no Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/479902) - lembrem que o o DE tem um cache, então os resultados lá pode estar desatualizados. Esses números eu peguei usando meus poderes mágicos de gerente!*</sup>

## Parabéns aos 5!

[image: Mitos da Propaganda]

No final acabamos com um total de 12 sugestões e, dentre elas, queremos umas 6 idéias pra transformar em banners. Então precisamos escolher agora quais são as favoritas de vocês.

Essa pergunta vai ter uma sugestão por resposta e vocês são livres pra votar nas suas favoritas. Novamente, **downvotes não vão contar**.

Na sexta-feira que vem (06/05/2016) vamos ter a lista final de ideias que vão virar nossos novos banners!

Comment: Não sabia que dava para alterar a autoria dos posts! :O

Comment: @Math É assim que eu roubo reputação, ué...

Comment: Somente o @Fabiano e eu com uma opção, estamos em desvantagem! kkkkkkkk

Comment: Mas as ideias são boas.

Comment: @Randrade São boas mesmo :D

Answer (score 36):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguém tem que fazer a versão IPv6 disso

Comment: Ia ficar muito feio :P

Comment: Ah eu sei que ::1 não é elegante mas daqui a pouco todo mundo vai usar mesmo

Comment: @jbueno tu dominas mesmo de design

Answer (score 16):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Na logo era para ser a que fala Stackoverflow em português, e não estouro de pilha, mas estava com preguiça de achar a certa!

Comment: Eu acho essa idéia a que mais tem apelo pra quem não conhece o site, mas com o logo original.

Comment: @Bacco Acho que convém deixar o comentário igual a original, minha ideia era com a logo original também, mas a preguiça não deixou. kkk

Comment: Eu lembro que vc tinha comentado que usou o que tava na mão, mas a idéia era o original mesmo. Só não quis deixar passar sem mencionar :)

Comment: achei fantástico...claro com pequenos ajustes..

Comment: @Dorathoto Eu concordo, mas fiquei com preguiça de melhorar quando fiz a versão original... kkkkkk
Mas valeu pelo elogio da ideia.

Comment: @Randrade, pare de programar e vá para o marketing! uahhuahua será um talento!..rs

Answer (score 12):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 11):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 10):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 10):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

## StackOverflow em português: Todas as linguagens na sua língua

Answer (score 5):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

## SO queres tirar uma dúvida? Tira em Português!

Answer (score 0):

## SO em Português podes perguntar!