# Banners pra que te quero!

Tags: debate, status-pronto, concurso

Depois de 2 semanas, mais de 30 idéias e quase 300 votos é chegada a hora...

As idéias ganhadoras do Upvote de Ouro 2016 são:

[image: jbueno]

---

[image: Randrade]

---

[image: jbueno]

---

[image: OnoSendai]

---

[image: Jorge B.]

---

[image: OnoSendai]

---

Parabéns a todos os vencedores!

## E agora?

Nada contra a *fantástica* habilidade de vocês no Photoshop e afins, mas agora é hora da nossa equipe de Design tomar as rédeas.

A ideia é transformar essas 6 ideias em 12 banners (cada um em 2 formatos: barra lateral e topo do site). Temos que ver coisas como ilustrações, direitos de uso de imagens, regras de publicidade no SO, entre outros, e fazer a versão final dos banners pra irem ao ar.

Se por algum motivo alguma dessas ideias não puder ser aproveitada, vamos continuar descendo a lista até chegar nos 12 banners que precisamos.

O plano é ter tudo pronto em 2 ou 3 semanas (nada de 6-8). Vocês vão ter uma prévia aqui antes deles irem pro ar.

Mais uma vez, muito obrigado à todo mundo pela participação. O site não seria nada sem a comunidade em torno dele. Vocês são o coração do Stack Overflow em Português, então nada melhor que decidirem como apresentá-lo ao mundo.

---

## Atualização

Durante o trabalho de criação da versão final dos banners, junto à equipe de design, nós conversamos sobre o banner do "malandro":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu disse no [primeiro post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999/) do concurso, nós tivemos [reclamações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1070/) justamente sobre um banner que brincava com linguagens de programação. É uma reclamação válida, e não queremos causar algum mal estar novamente com os novos banners. Além disso, temos algumas preocupações com a referência à "malandro".

Dito isso, achamos melhor passar pra próxima opção na [votação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5022/). A outra sugestão do OnoSendai:
[image: OnoSendai]

A equipe de design já está trabalhando com as ideias de vocês e esperamos ter a versão final de cada banner até o fim do mês.

---

## Atualização 2

A boa notícia é que os banners estão praticamente prontos! A má é que um deles não deu certo... E a pior é que é *outro* do OnoSendai:
[image: OnoSendai]

A melhor é que, como o OnoSendai é bastante prolífico na arte de criar banners, **se** o banner for substituido por outro, o próximo mais votado é justamente do OnoSendai:
[image: OnoSendai]

Eu digo **se** porque pode não haver tempo hábil pra fazer mais um banner, e vai depender da carga da equipe de design. Estamos aguardando a resposta deles.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/waU26.png essa é a mais legal, só tinha que mudar a cor meio bege das frases "para quem fala em português" e "em português" no logo. No fundo verde ficou estranha...

Comment: @PeterParker usei o logo oficial, quis manter as cores, mas tens razão, branco provavelmente ficava melhor.

Comment: @JorgeB. "Para quem fala **em** Português" está certo? Não deveria ser sem o "Para quem fala Português"? Que eu saiba o verbo "falar" é transitivo direto.

Comment: @Math ora ai está uma boa pergunta para o PL :P

Comment: @Math O certo é "Para quem fala português". Esse uso do verbo falar no sentido de "conhecer uma língua" é transitivo direto, embora haja outros usos que são transitivos indiretos ou intransitivos. O "falar no idioma X" é vício que a gente pega de dizer que uma coisa "está no idioma X" ou que "eu quero dizer tal coisa no idioma X".

Comment: Vai ter a parte 3? :(

Comment: Gabe só uma correção, depois de falar com o pessoal do PL fiquei convencido que é como o @Math diz, "SÓ para quem fala Português!"

Comment: De alguma coisa valeu o *carpet bombing* de banners!

Comment: essa é muito boa http://i.stack.imgur.com/nqhAG.jpg hehe