# Abram alas pros novos banners!

Tags: debate

Com todas as [mudanças de última hora](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5049/) acabou levando mais do que o esperado, mas nossos banners estão prontos!

Antes de qualquer coisa, mais uma vez obrigado à todo mundo que participou do [concurso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999/)!
* *palmas* *

E obrigado ao [Paweł](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/36343/pawe%C5%82) por ter dado aquela ajeitada na aparência!
* *palmas* *

Vamos então à eles!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eles vão começar a ser exibidos no SOen, para IPs no Brasil e Portugal, além de pessoas que tenham seus navegadores em Português, à partir dessa segunda feira (13/06/2016).

Esperamos que gostem, e que eles ajudem a apresentar nossa comunidade à todos que ainda não nos conhecem!

---

## Atualização

Depois de deliberar, com [brasileiras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/901/rla4) e [portugueses](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat), sobre os pontos [levantados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5131) pelo Victor Stafusa sobre possíveis conotações negativas nos banners, decidimos seguir em frente e usar todos eles.

Como [eu disse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5128/abram-alas-pros-novos-banners/5134#comment18560_5131), a preocupação era de que os banners pudessem ser inadvertidamente excludentes ou ofensivos, e que pudessem ferir a imagem da comunidade. Queremos que eles sejam convidativos e representem bem a nossa comunidade, para que mais pessoas possam se juntar à ela.

Remeter ao passado não é um problema nesse sentido. Pode até não agradar à todos, mas não fere nossa imagem ou passa alguma ideia negativa. Além disso, os banners são de lusófonos, para lusófonos. Representam nossa cultura e nossa história - compartilhada e individual. Camões, Pessoa ou Carmen Miranda. São imagens reconhecidas por quem fala português. E boas representações de quem somos.

Ainda assim, mais uma vez agradeço ao Victor Stafusa, por levantar suas preocupações e nos fazer pensar ainda mais a fundo sobre a imagem que queremos passar.

Além disso, os problemas com o banner da tradução foram resolvidos!

---

## Atualização 2

Os banners estão no ar!

Comment: O que é "berenguendém"?

Comment: Precisa acertar a acentuação no menu arredondado :)

Comment: @Sergio teria que ser uma gíria conhecia aí para Portugueses de Portugal, né

Comment: [berenguendém](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/berenguend%C3%A9m/)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters obrigado. É tipo "não tem só coisa bonita" tem código bonito e feio? :) Estou a brincar, agora que sei o que quer dizer acho bom tb :)

Comment: @Sergio a Carmem Miranda nasceu aí, não temos nada com isso :D

Comment: Achei o terceiro, o quarto e o último horríveis. Não gostei desses.

Comment: Nossa ficaram ótimos (arte) e o segundo ficou ao meu ver o melhor de todos, tanto em arte quanto a ideia :D

Comment: @Sergio sou brasileiro e me fiz a mesma pergunta :/

Comment: @Bacco Diz no de tradução par ao português? Se sim, fiquei em dúvida se poderia ser algum em relação ao Português de Portugal.

Comment: Não posso negar que é um orgulho ver as nossas ideias num banner da rede SE. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa horrível se refere a arte ou a ideia? Eu não gostei muito da ideias destes, pois não são tão intuitivos quanto os demais, mas a arte me parece boa.

Comment: @Sergio Esse é um trecho de uma música de Carmem Miranda, '*South American Way*' [No tabuleiro tem de tudo que convém
/ Mas só lhe falta, ai, ai berenguendéns
]. É um tipo de ornamento usado pelas baianas em dias festivos.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters noooon, essa definição aí está errada =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A ideia. Na minha opinião, reforçam estereótipos culturais negativos e ultrapassados.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Não queremos que este seja o caso. Que estereótipos estão sendo reforçados?

Comment: @Gabe Agora fiquei curioso também, até porquê 2 são meus - onde de propósito escolhi um que fosse de fácil reconhecimento como brasileiro (o de Carmem Miranda, que menciona que temos tudo menos o que é inútil) e outro português (Fernando Pessoa), as duas maiores categorias demográficas do SOPT.

Comment: @OnoSendai Quando nós fizemos a revisão dos vencedores, o do "malandro" tinha chamado nossa atenção como potencialmente problemático. O resto nos pareceu bastante direto, sem nenhuma conotação negativa (ou piada). Também estou curioso.

Comment: @Gabe *In all fairness* a do malandro era uma piada. =) Estes, ao contrário, são sérios e positivos.

Comment: @OnoSendai Foi como eu, e outros, entendemos também. Por isso a preocupação.

Comment: @Gabe A caravela reforça a ideia de colonização e de desbravamento de mares desconhecidos, algo que não tem mais sentido há uns 350 ou 400 anos. A Carmen Miranda, uma personagem exótica e carnavalesca que propagandeava aos gringos um país tropical de uns 70 anos atrás (imagem que às vezes acabava associando o Brasil a turismo sexual, mesmo que esse não fosse o propósito dela). Tudo isso remete ao passado, exibindo os países lusófonos como culturas há muito não mais existentes, e falha em não mostrar o SO.PT como uma comunidade de programação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Se importa de colocar uma resposta com suas preocupações, para podermos discutí-las? Não quero dominar os comentários do post

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho que é uma escolha de ponto de vista. A caravela evoca exploração, um tema muito apropriado se levarmos em consideração que é o que mais fazemos como desenvolvedores em tecnologias modernas - e ainda é visto desta maneira por membros da comunidade lusófona. Quanto à Carmem Miranda, também considero a mensagem como positiva e clara: 'só não tem enrolação.' Infelizmente não temos uma Ada Lovelace, mas ainda sabemos usar a leveza e alegria ao nosso favor.

Comment: @Gabe já agora em que sito aparecem os banners? Acho que nunca vi nenhum lol.

Comment: @JorgeB. Iam pro ar essa segunda-feira, mas a discussão em torno dos banners atrasou um pouco até sabermos o que fazer

Comment: @Gabe não percebeste. Eu nunca vi banners nenhuns. Não sei onde deveriam aparecer sequer.

Comment: @Gabe O meu banner preferido é o segundo, mas me parece que a escrita esta errada, eu não tenho certeza, mas me parece que tem dois erros de acentos em `Pàgina`  e `portuguès` e outra coisa usaram `Ver Origem da Pagina`, mas eu não tenho certeza se isso é portugues europeu ou se alguém tentou traduzir do inglês e acabou que as frases perderam sentido.

Comment: Acessei o site do @Paweł, mal o conheço mas já considero pacas... quero dizer já sou fã! O estilo de design dele é incrível, parabéns pela ajeitada que fez nos banners!

Comment: @JorgeB. Topo da página, barra lateral abaixo do "quadro de avisos"

Comment: Não deu para perceber muito.

Comment: A correção do banner 2 ficou ótima, parabéns a todos vocês! Meu banner preferido :D

Comment: @Gabe mas só aparece no SOen? A do topo nem consigo encontrar...

Comment: @JorgeB. Só no SOen.... E você tem que dar "sorte" `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Após ler a [resposta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5131/3635) e ler todos comentários eu decidi *pra mim mesmo*, sendo aceito ou não estes tais banners, que temos banners pra todos gostos, desde:

- Frase de referencia (no da caravela)
- Conheça Fernando Pessoa
- Conheça Carmen Miranda, ou gírias da época
- Conheça o plugin pra tradução em navegadores
- Saiba o que significa 127.0.0.1
- Tenha gostado da palavra "só" com o efeito no acento usando o icone da comunidade

Em outras palavras, nem todos os banners irão agradar a todos usuários, mas pelo menos um banner irá agradar, temos banners para diferentes gostos, assim acho que devemos manter todos, mesmo que um ou dois não sejam intuitivos a todos.

> Isto era um comentário, mas resolvi transformar em uma resposta após uma conversa com Randrade

Answer (score 5):

Bem, não gostei de três dos itens. Não queria postar uma resposta, pois sei que serei extremamente negativado, atacado e criticado, ainda mais porque eu não estava por aqui na época em que se deu a maior parte do debate acerca dos banners e vim aqui cair de paraquedas para criticar.

Entretanto, o Gabe me convidou a responder para não dominar os comentários da pergunta, e após tomar uma certa coragem diante da certeza da chuva de downvotes e comentários em discordância que vou receber, aqui vai minha opinião. Se isso porventura ganhar uma pontuação bastante negativa e um monte de comentários criticando mais rapidamente do que eu imagino (tipo -10 em um só dia), talvez eu vá deletar essa resposta e permanecer em silêncio porque não estou com muito saco e paciência ultimamente para ficar servindo de alvo ao debater esse tipo de coisa na internet.

Os que não gostei são esses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eles têm em comum? Todos eles estão olhando para o passado! O primeiro, é uma fotografia em preto-e-branco. O segundo, uma personagem exótica que atuava há uns 80 ou 70 anos atrás. O último, algo que aparece nos livros de história narrando algo que ocorreu há alguns séculos.

A Carmen Miranda em especial tem algo mais grave. Há gringos que têm mania de achar que:

> Brasil = Futebol + Mulher pelada + Carnaval + Bananas

Bem, a Carmen Miranda, apesar de todo o seu talento e genialidade, foi uma das maiores contribuições para o surgimento deste estereótipo (com exceção da parte do futebol), embora provavelmente isso nunca foi a intenção dela. Uma vez que ela era a única representante conhecida pelos gringos sobre a cultura brasileira nos anos 1930 e 1940, sendo ela uma cantora e dançarina exótica, carnavalesca a cantar sobre um país tropical, desfilando frutas tropicais, inclusive várias bananas, acabou emplacando no resto do mundo essa imagem completamente irreal e fantasiosa do Brasil. Depois disso, com os jogadores de futebol, e com as mulheres peladas ou quase peladas do carnaval, deu no que deu, este é o estereótipo que os gringos têm sobre o Brasil, estereótipo que só serve para estimular o turismo sexual. Se bem que por outro lado, mulher pelada e carnaval iriam virar estereótipos cedo ou tarde com ou sem ela.

Quanto a caravela, convenhamos que a época disso já passou há uns 350 ou 400 anos pelo menos. Com certeza é possível obter-se referências positivas à Brasil e Portugal bem mais modernas e atuais do que isso. É verdade que as caravelas passam a ideia de descobrimento, mas também passam a ideia de colonização e principalmente a ideia de algo antigo. Aliás, vejo isso como um estereótipo de que Portugal é o país das caravelas, coisa que corresponderia a verdade se estivéssemos há uns quatro ou cinco séculos atrás, mas hoje em dia é apenas parte dos livros de história.

O SO.PT é uma comunidade sobre programação, e muitas das nossas perguntas e respostas versam sobre tecnologia de ponta olhando para o futuro. Isso contrasta bastante com esses banners em específico.

Se isso fosse uma comunidade de história em língua portuguesa, o primeiro e o terceiro desses provavelmente estariam bem e sobre o segundo eu teria muito menos o que dizer. Mas essa não é uma comunidade sobre história, e sim sobre programação.

Comment: Três pontos. Acredito que você tenha entendido errado a maneira como um posto do Meta funciona - pontos negativos não querem dizer que a resposta é ruim; apenas que quem votou não concorda com você; sua contribuição é mais do que bem-vinda. Segundo, sendo o criador de dois dos banners, eu irei me abster de votar. Terceiro... talvez valesse a pena mudar a expressão *"Os gringos tem mania de achar que: Brasil = Futebol + Mulher pelada + Carnaval + Bananas"* - alguns podem pensar que soa como preconceito de sua parte. Eu trabalho com 'gringos' e não acho que esta expressão seja a opinião deles.

Comment: @OnoSendai Quanto ao primeiro ponto, sei que quem vota pode estar apenas não concordando, e que os downvotes no meta não interferem na minha reputação no site principal, mas já esquentei muito a cabeça nos metas deste e de outros sites da SE em discussões passadas. Quanto ao "*Os gingos tem mania*" eu editei para "*Há gringos que têm mania*", uma vez que eu sem querer acabei generalizando e não era essa minha intenção. De fato é uma minoria bem pequena, porém irritante, deles que têm essa visão.

Comment: Olha o ponto que mais concordo e que tentei expressar no meu comentário é justamente este de somos uma comunidade de programadores, eu disse http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5128/abram-alas-pros-novos-banners#comment18496_5128 ... quero dizer que realmente não tem sentido algum (opinião) pra comunidade, não só porque mostram coisas antigas, mas muita gente hoje não entende nada sobre as imagens, as ideias são boas, mas não pro site... penso eu assim.

Comment: Sendo sincero acho que estás a ser exagerado. A caravela antes de tudo tem a ver com história, nunca me passaria pela cabeça associar isso a colonização. Mas também não se esqueça que os brasileiros, na maioria são descendentes de portugueses. Acho que a caravela só dá ideia do que é falar português. Quanto à Carmen, eu que sou estrangeiro não acho nada que esteja associado a algo terrível, mas como não sou Brasileiro não posso ter a certeza. Fernando Pessoa nem preciso dizer nada.

Comment: Quanto aos seus argumentos de serem antigas e estarem mais direcionadas com um site de línguas, permite-me discordar. É só uma demonstração de que afinal há um site de programação que "fala" português, parecem-me banners atrativos e que chamam a atenção das pessoas para isso mesmo. Se colocasses algo relacionado com a programação, em nada se diferenciava do SOen.

Comment: Já agora eu sou Gringo?

Comment: Estranhei bastante as vossas reações. Para mim as 3 imagens reforçam a ideia de "é em português", e acho que é essa a ideia dos banners.

Comment: @JorgeB. Que bom que funciona para você. Eu não disse que estavam direcionadas a um site de línguas, e sim a um site de história. Para mim a única coisa que reforça a ideia de "é em português" é o texto, pois as imagens não me parecem estar indo neste sentido. Quanto a algo relacionado a programação não se diferenciar do SOen, eu discordo, embora concordaria com a afirmação de que fazer a diferenciação não seria tarefa fácil.

Comment: É sério que a sua justificativa pra não gostar do primeiro banner é pelo motivo de ser uma imagem em preto e branco?

Comment: Após ler a resposta e ler todos comentários eu decidi pra mim mesmo, sendo aceito ou não estes banners temos banners pra todos gostos, desde quem conheça as frase de referencia (no da caravela), conheça Fernando Pessoa, conheça Carmen Miranda, conheça o plugin pra tradução em navegadores, saiba o que significa 127.0.0.1 e tenha gostado da palavra "só" com o efeito no acento... todos os banners não irão agradar a todos, mas pelo menos um irá agradar, ou seja temos banners pra diferentes gostos, assim acho que devemos manter todos.

Comment: @JorgeB. precisa ter mais aulas de história/geografia brasileira, a maioria não são descentes de portugueses :D + uma crença popular :D Como assim "Quanto à Carmen, eu que sou estrangeiro não acho nada que esteja associado a algo terrível, mas como não sou Brasileiro não posso ter a certeza. "?

Comment: Obrigado, Victor. Li seu post, e os comentários, e vou conversar com outras pessoas pra ver o que fazer. Já adianto que nossa preocupação maior é com os banners passarem alguma imagem excludente ou que reflita estereótipos negativos. Isso levando em consideração o conteúdo dos banners e o fato de que eles serão mostrados *exclusivamente* para lusófonos. Não representam nosso site para o "mundo", representam nosso site para pessoas como nós, que compartilham nossa cultura. Você levantou pontos relevantes sobre alguns dos banners e, independente da decisão, fez muito bem em iniciar a discussão.

Comment: @bigown expressei-me mal, o que quis dizer que duma forma ou de outra foram portugueses, os "primeiros" brasileiros. Eu bem sei que há muita descendência Italiana, Alemã e Africana, muito mais que portuguesa.

Comment: Brasil = Brasil + Feijoada